# EF / MVC4 / SQL Server: ALTER TABLE and FOREIGN KEY constraint options?

Tags: sql-server, entity-framework, asp.net-mvc-4

I am coding with Entity Framework MVC4 and SQL Server and am running into an error when I create this relationship:

```
Jobs.JobID = Docs.JobID
```

The error:

> The ALTER TABLE statement conflicted with the FOREIGN KEY constraint

I know that in order to fix this I have to do one of the following:

1. Delete all table data and then create the relationship.
2. Add or Remove records where all the `JobID` are missing/null then create the relationship.

The problem is, there are about 25,000+ records with IDs missing so I want to know if changing the relationship options in SQL Server will fix this issue w/o causing problems? I see the following:

- Check Existing Data On Creation: Yes
- Enforce For Replication: Yes
- Enforce Foreign Key Constraint: Yes

Does anyone know if this will fix the problem and not cause any issues when trying to link data with MVC4 using `.Include` command? Getting linked data to show using the `.Include` command is the real purpose for why I am doing this but I'm skeptical of how much it will affect the way the .edmx file works, Entity Framework commands, or the project in general.

Maybe there is an easier way to solve this, or maybe adding/removing the 25k records is the only way to solve this when working with MVC4/EF, but I am not sure?  Let me know the correct way to go about this.  Thank you!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I don't know of a way of doing this from the EF model. But you can create such a foreign key on Sql Server and then update your EF model via the 'Update Model from Data' command.

First you would create a 'disabled' FK. And then you enable the FK without checking existing data.

```
-- creates a foreign key -> but it is disabled
ALTER TABLE dbo.T2 WITH NOCHECK 
ADD CONSTRAINT FK_T2_T1 
FOREIGN KEY (Fk) REFERENCES dbo.T1(Id);

-- now enable it without checking the existing data in the table:
ALTER TABLE dbo.T2
CHECK CONSTRAINT FK_T2_T1;

-- fyi, the syntax for enabling AND checking integrity looks like this:
ALTER TABLE dbo.T2
WITH CHECK CHECK CONSTRAINT FK_T2_T1;
```

See http://sqlfiddle.com/#!3/eccf72/4

Comment: Thanks for your response. Do you think the equivalent of this is Enforce Foreign Key Constraint: No and Check Existing Data On Creation = No?  I would like to try that first in the wizard if it's the same.

Comment: I would assume so. I think 'Enforce Foreign Key Constraint' is the equivalent of 'FK enabled yes|no' and for when you enable the key again the 'Check Existing Data On Creation' option comes into play.

Comment: I think this worked but I will have to do some more coding and testing to make sure it didn't cause problems elsewhere, before I mark this as the correct answer.  Thanks for your help and hopefully all is well by the time I am done testing!

Comment: Also FYI: I used the Relationships Wizard in SQL Server Management Studio and not the SQL above, changing Check Existing Data On Creation and Enforce Foreign Key Constraint = NO and leaving Enforce Replication = YES.

Comment: Works great so far. Haven't run into any issues with data yet and hope it stays that way, thanks!